# Geoserver gwc rest api - how can I edit config

Tags: geowebcache, geoserver-rest-api

Is there a way to change geoserver gwc-gs.xml through a rest interface? I want to be able to set cacheLayersByDefault to false.

Comment: So why not just edit it by hand?

Comment: There are a lot of scenarios where you may not be able do it by hand. I think this is a legitimate and clear question, I don't understand the close-votes.

Comment: The [Docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/rest/index.html#gwc-rest) does not provide any information. If here know one knows, maybe the GeoServer Mailing List is the better place to ask.

Comment: I am using Ansible to provision the geoserver setup and I use the geoserver rest services for contact config, and setup of workspaces, stores and layers, i.e. I want to be independent of the web interface.

I can solve this by replacing the gwc-gs.xml file with the one with the desired settings, but before doing that I wondered if there was a rest interface for common gwc config I could use instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, the GeoWebCache Rest API is used to control the cache rather than the GeoServer Rest API which is used to control the configuration of the server.

If this is important to your work you could sponsor the improvement.